# Kind attribute metadata value question for HTML5

Tags: html

what does the kind attributes metadata value description below mean for us dummies?

metadata value description:

`Tracks intended for use from script`

Answer (score 0):

It means that data in that track is not intended to be automatically displayed to the user, as subtitles would be, but it may contain information useful to a script.  For example a collection of bookmarks, or cues to trigger other things on the page as the video is playing - think of a video of a presentation playing alongside a frame containing the slides.